# Can I have a subdomain of php application on asp.net application

Tags: php, asp.net, windows, iis, hosting

I have an asp.net web application hosted and I would like to add a sub-domain (or sub-directory) and run/host a php application in it.

How would i do this?

Comment: As long as your hosting supports php, you can create sub-domain in php

Comment: @Ratheesh How? How does your sub-domain gets resolved?

Comment: sub-domain and sub-directory are to different things what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0):

A subdomain would be nicer from a technical standpoint:

- You could make your DNS route the subdomain.yourdomain.com to a different Server then yourdomain.com
- You could add different IIS bindings for subdomain.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com in IIS.

For a sub-directory you'd have to run php in IIS as well, [here is a guide](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-a-php-website-on-iis/configure-a-php-website-on-iis) in how to set it up: You can also run an php website in iis.

You could also run php on Apache and dotnet in IIS. The only downside: If you try to run both apps on 1 server, only 1 (IIS or apache) Can listen for http traffic on port 80 (the default port). so you'd have to host 1 on a different port (eg for port 81: yourdomain.com:81) which i wouldn't advice for a production website.

You could make a tiny application which receives every request and forwards the http request to the right application on a different port. This is called a reverse proxy.

Comment: IIS can also run PHP. so no need for another Apache instance

Comment: @bansi i was just adding another possibility. but yes you are right (as i also stated in my answer `you'd have to run php in IIS as well`.)